# Laravel 5.6 Migration Issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm receiving this error when attempting to perform a migration of tables in Laravel 5.6 (using MAMP 4 / Macbook Pro). Double checked settings and they work fine (able to access my database with Sequel Pro):

Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel_database and table_name = migrations)

```
              at /Users/User1/Desktop/LaravelFolder/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
                660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
                661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
                662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
                663|         catch (Exception $e) {
              > 664|             throw new QueryException(
                665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
                666|             );
                667|         }
                668|

              Exception trace:

              1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory")
                  /Users/User1/Desktop/LaravelFolder/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68

              2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=localhost;port=8889;dbname=laravel_database", "root", "root", [])
                  /Users/User1/Desktop/LaravelFolder/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68
```

Comment: Did you look at all the existing answers on this problem?

Comment: I'm using Homestead VM and not MAMP but I couldn't point at localhost in my .env file, had to be the IP of my VM machine. Same thing where I can access it via localhost (127.0.0.1) with Sequel Pro

Comment: Make sure to run `artisan` commands while SSH'ed into your Homestead VM.

Comment: Where did you setup mysql credentials in case .env not readable? Is it database.php file?

Comment: means it cannot connect to ur db